# Setting the default startDate and endDate properties for react-dates

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

Setting default values for startDate and endDate for the react-dates  component breaks the component with the error below:

My react version: 
"react": "^16.5.2"
"react-dates": "^18.1.0"

Component code:

```
import React from 'react'

import 'react-dates/initialize';
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-dates';
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';

class DateRangeSelector extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      startDate: moment().subtract(2, 'year'),
      endDate: moment(),
      // focusedInput: 'startDate'
    }

  }

  render() {

    return (

      <DateRangePicker
        startDate={this.state.startDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
        startDateId={this.props.startDateInputId} // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        endDate={this.state.endDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
        endDateId={this.props.endDateInputId} // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => this.setState({ startDate, endDate })}
        isOutsideRange={() => false}
        focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,            
        onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      />


    )

  }

}

DateRangeSelector.defaultProps = {
  startDateInputId: 'start-date-field',
  endDateInputId: 'end-date-field',
}

export default DateRangeSelector
```

**Error:**

```
DayPickerRangeController.js:1336 Uncaught TypeError: day.isBetween is not a function
    at DayPickerRangeController.isInSelectedSpan (DayPickerRangeController.js:1336)
    at Object.selectedSpan [as selected-span] (DayPickerRangeController.js:383)
    at DayPickerRangeController.js:1074
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at DayPickerRangeController.getModifiersForDay (DayPickerRangeController.js:1073)
    at DayPickerRangeController.js:1058
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at DayPickerRangeController.js:1057
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at DayPickerRangeController.getModifiers (DayPickerRangeController.js:1055)
isInSelectedSpan @ DayPickerRangeController.js:1336
selectedSpan @ DayPickerRangeController.js:383
(anonymous) @ DayPickerRangeController.js:1074
getModifiersForDay @ DayPickerRangeController.js:1073
(anonymous) @ DayPickerRangeController.js:1058
(anonymous) @ DayPickerRangeController.js:1057
getModifiers @ DayPickerRangeController.js:1055
getStateForNewMonth @ DayPickerRangeController.js:1099
DayPickerRangeController @ DayPickerRangeController.js:439
constructClassInstance @ react-dom.development.js:11769
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:13491
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:14090
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:16416
workLoop @ react-dom.development.js:16454
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:145
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:195
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:248
replayUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:15745
renderRoot @ react-dom.development.js:16548
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:17387
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:17295
performSyncWork @ react-dom.development.js:17267
interactiveUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:17558
interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2208
dispatchInteractiveEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4913
react-dom.development.js:14550 The above error occurred in the <DayPickerRangeController> component:
    in DayPickerRangeController (created by DateRangePicker)
    in div (created by DateRangePicker)
    in div (created by OutsideClickHandler)
    in OutsideClickHandler (created by DateRangePicker)
    in div (created by DateRangePicker)
    in DateRangePicker (created by withStyles(DateRangePicker))
    in withStyles(DateRangePicker) (created by DateRangeSelector)
    in div (created by DateRangeSelector)
    in div (created by DateRangeSelector)
    in DateRangeSelector
```

Comment: what does this mean isOutsideRange={() => false}?

Comment: @HaiderAli, isOutsideRange decides the date range that are not allowed for user selection. by setting that to return false, it allows the user to select any dates. more here: https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/239

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to follow the [docs](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates#daterangepicker) and got it to work. Try utilizing React `state` instead of `defaultProps`. Please note, that there's some `CSS` jank going on with the module.

Working example:

[image: Edit React Dates Example]

**components/DateRangeSelector/index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-dates";
import moment from "moment";
import "./styles.css";

class DateRangeSelector extends Component {
  state = {
    startDate: moment().subtract(2, "year"),
    endDate: moment(),
    focusedInput: null
  };

  handleDateChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) =>
    this.setState({ startDate, endDate });

  handleFocusChange = focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput });

  render = () => (
    <DateRangePicker
      endDate={this.state.endDate}
      endDateId="endDate"
      focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput}
      isOutsideRange={() => null}
      onDatesChange={this.handleDateChange}
      onFocusChange={this.handleFocusChange}
      startDate={this.state.startDate}
      startDateId="startDate"
    />
  );
}

export default DateRangeSelector;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import DateRangeSelector from "./components/DateRangeSelector";
import "react-dates/initialize";
import "react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <h2>Date Range Picker</h2>
    <DateRangeSelector />
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**components/DateRangeSelector/styles.css**

```
.DateRangePickerInput_arrow {
  width: 40px;
}

.DateInput_input {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**styles.css**

```
.app {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank You @matt :)